# How could a Ruby process put limit to its CPU usage?

Tags: ruby, performance

Let say I want a Ruby process to not use more than 15% of the CPU. Is it possible? How?

Comment: maybe it'll help - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cpu-usage-limiter-for-linux/

Comment: this is handled by the operating system, such as ulimit on unixes.  This question belongs on serverfault

Comment: @DGM, I agree that usually this is best solved by using the OS, however I disagree this is off-topic. SO topics are specific questions related to programming, including tools commonly used. I think this question squeaks by, especially in light of the answer by @mu is too short.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try using [`Process.setrlimit`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-setrlimit) from the standard core:

> Sets the resource limit of the process.

This looks like it is just a wrapper around the [`setrlimit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setrlimit.html) from the C library so it may only be available on Unix-ish platforms. `setrlimit` doesn't support CPU percentage limits but it does support limiting CPU time in seconds.

If you're just trying to keep your Ruby process from hogging the whole CPU then you could try adjusting its priority with [`Process.setpriority`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Process.html#method-c-setpriority) which is just a wrapper around libc's [`setpriority`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpriority.html) and offers some control over your process's scheduling priority. Again, availability will probably be limited by your platform but it should work on Linux, OSX, or any other Unix-ish system.

Comment: unfortunately Process.setpriority() function is unimplemented on windows :|

Comment: @rogerdpack: I don't know enough about Windows to know what to do. Presumably there is a similar API in Windows that you could wrap in a thin layer of C-to-Ruby or something, there might even be a general purpose Windows gem that would help you access whatever API Windows has for process management and limiting.

Comment: @rogerdpack: Maybe there is something in http://win32utils.rubyforge.org that would help, but again I don't know enough about Windows to say more.

Comment: Nice, or maybe FFI or some odd, thanks for the tip @muistooshort